# Problem running Asymptote

Tags: installing, asymptote

I cant seem to to run asymptote after installing ghostscript, gsview, and MikTex please help me. All i get when i write the asy command in the cmd is this. I have a Windows 7 Ultimate installed on my PC.[image: asymptote command error].

**PS:-** I just remembered that as I have installed a fresh Windows I dont have Visual Studio C++, could that be the reason. If any other information is necessary please ask for it.

Comment: Actually it looks like you have Asymptote running in the window, in [interactive mode](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/doc/Drawing-in-interactive-mode.html#Drawing-in-interactive-mode).

Comment: Hmm... so what do i do, you see I am just a noob at latex right now.

Comment: Several possibilities. You can change how you are launching Asymptote. You can use Asymptote within LaTeX, using either `asypictureB` or `latexmk` to launch Asymptote automatically. Or, within interactive mode, you can type `input "<filename>"` on one line (no `.asy` suffix) and `shipout("<filename>")` on the next.

Comment: For the first (most conventional) option, to change how you launch Asymptote: You want to go to the ordinary command-line (NOT Asymptote itself; e.g., don't click on any Asymptote icon), and type `asy <filename>`.

Comment: Which filename am I supposed to type in the cmd, sorry if i am being a pain.

Comment: If you wrote an Asymptote file you're trying to run, the name of that file. If you wrote a filename `foo.tex` using the Asymptote package and then ran `latex` on it, you want to run `asy foo-*.asy` if I recall correctly. (If that doesn't work try it with `_` instead of `-`.)

Comment: I haven't written any files with asymptote as of now, so should the example files work.

Comment: If you're just trying to get a feel for Asymptote, you're probably better off just typing commands in interactive mode. See the link in my first comment. But yes, if you have example files from somewhere they will probably work provided they're in the same directory as you are in when you launch `asymptote`.

Comment: when i wrote the command asy alignedaxis (alignedaxis being the example file preloaded in the examples folder) it shoes the following error:-could not load module 'alignedaxis'.

Comment: See my edited comment. In this case, you need to `cd` to the examples folder before running `asy alignedaxis`.

Comment: My motive for installing asymptote is to draw diagram for maths to be written in the latex code that I would write for asking questions in math stackexchange.

Comment: Okay now there's no error dialogue in the command prompt when i did what you told me to but after writing the command nothing happens .

Comment: Thanks for your patience, I cant thank you enough, I had been trying to figure it out for 4 days now.

Comment: You won't be able to post this as code on Math SE and have it display the diagram. You could post the diagram as an image (PNG or whatever). To view the result of `asy alignedaxis`, you probably need to open the resulting file in a suitable viewer.